# When I click tiktok like butten with selenium, it reverts after a few seconds

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

**After a few seconds, when I click tiktok, it automatically reverts to the previous state**

After a few seconds, when I click tiktok, it automatically reverts to the previous state

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from textwrap import wrap
import time
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 4')
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_argument("window-size=810,1080")
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.169 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
# options.add_argument('--start-fullscreen')
# options.add_argument('--single-process')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
# options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
# options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\DELL\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.execute_cdp_cmd("Page.addScriptToEvaluateOnNewDocument", {
    "source":
        "const newProto = navigator.__proto__;"
        "delete newProto.webdriver;"
        "navigator.__proto__ = newProto;"
})


driver.get("https://www.tiktok.com/@googlemapsfun/video/7062048347451870469?is_copy_url=1&is_from_webapp=v1")

like = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '(//*[@data-e2e="feed-video"])')

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(like)
actions.double_click()
actions.perform()



time.sleep(150)
```

After a few seconds, when I click tiktok, it automatically reverts to the previous state

Comment: I've read and also ran your code, but didn't get your exact question. What do you want to do? What is your goal and exit criteria of doing this test?

Comment: @MohammadMonfared I am actually trying to press the tiktok like button..which I manage to do, but with selenium I encounter a problem when I press the like button. It reverts back to unlike after a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I have no reputation that would write to you in the comment, so I wrote here.
Hey! Did you get the desired? I did even this way, and still fail. He also puts like, and then tiktok removes him

```
# find element

like = DRIVER.find_element_by_tag_name('video')

# find height browser navigation panel

browser_navigation_panel_height = DRIVER.execute_script('return window.outerHeight - window.innerHeight;')

# find x and y for click on like

x = like.location["x"]
y = DRIVER.find_element_by_tag_name('video').location["y"] + browser_navigation_panel_height

# generation random coords

coord = random.randint(x, y)

# Performs mouse move action onto the element

actions = ActionChains(driver)

actions.move_by_offset(coord, coord)
actions.click()
actions.move_by_offset(coord, coord)
actions.click()
actions.perform()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).